# how to save incoming XML in SOAP in java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I have a requirement like, I get a huge xml in SOAP body to my endpoint and I need to manipulate this xml and save it as a file.
I am stuck how to do this?

`<animal>
  <birds>
   <falcon>...
</animal>`

Should I create class objects for each animal(parent), birds(child), falcon(child of birds) etc to fit this xml into? or Do I have any other option?

```
@Webmethod
public AnimalReturnClass getXML(Animal inputXMLObj)
```

So, in short how to process incoming xml in SOAP request?

Thanks.

Comment: Soap Webservices in java can be developed in may ways. Here is a simple way to implement it. I hope the given link would help you, http://www.journaldev.com/9131/soap-webservices-in-java-example-eclipse    https://gist.github.com/kdelfour/b2a449a1bac23e3baec8

Comment: @Ashok Raj You can simply convert inputXMLObj to String and then you can manipulate using regex ,etc and then finally you can write it to a file.
It totally depends on what is the manipulation you want to do?